# Custom annotation not working with @JsonProperty

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-annotations

I've run into a situation where I need to validate a field inside an object conditionally. More specifically, I have one class `PhoneType` which contains two fields

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class PhoneType {

  @JsonProperty("@CountryCode")
  private String countryCode;

  @JsonProperty("@Number")
  private String number;

}
```

The class `PhoneType` is used in three places,

```java
@Getter
@Setter
class PersonContact {
  @JsonProperty("Mobile")
  private PhoneType mobile;

  @JsonProperty("WorkPhone")
  private PhoneType workPhone;

  @JsonProperty("OfficeFax")
  private PhoneType officeFax;
}
```

However, with `mobile`, there should be an additional validation rule applied to the `number` field. The `number` must be a number with length of 10.

I have two possible solutions in mind:

- Create a custom annotation to validate `number` for `mobile`
- Validate `number` using Jackson's `StdConverter`

Here are the implementation of both solutions

```java
public class ContactConverter extends StdConverter<PersonContact, PersonContact> {

  @SneakyThrows
  @Override
  public PersonContact convert(PersonContact personContact) {

    boolean validMobilePhone = Pattern.compile("\\d{10}")
        .matcher(relatedPersonContact.getMobileNumber())
        .matches();

    if (BooleanUtils.isFalse(validMobilePhone)) {
      var errorMessage = String.format(INVALID_MOBILE_NUMBER, personContact.getMobileNumber());
      throw new JsonParseException(null, errorMessage);
    }

    return personContact;
  }
}
```

`Converter` is used like this

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonDeserialize(converter = ContactConverter.class)
public class PersonContact {

  @JsonProperty("@Email")
  private String email;

  @JsonProperty("WorkPhone")
  private PhoneType workPhone;

  @JsonProperty("Mobile")
  private PhoneType mobile;
}
```

This is the code for custom annotation, however it's not working

```java
  @Retention(RUNTIME)
  @Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
  @Constraint(validatedBy = MobilePhoneNumberValidator.class)
  @interface Phone {
    String format() default "";
    String message() default "Invalid phone number";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
  }

  static class MobilePhoneNumberValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Phone, PhoneType> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(Phone constraintAnnotation) {
      System.out.println("test");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(PhoneType phoneType, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
      System.out.println("test again");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

and this is how I use it

```java
  @Phone(format = "\\d{10}")
  @JsonProperty("Mobile")
  private PhoneType mobile;
```

However, the code inside the Validator is not executed.

I wonder if there is anything wrong with the custom annotation. This is SpringBoot 2.3.0, I can't think of any other reason why the custom annotation is not working.

Please help if you know there is a legit way handling dynamic annotation in Java, or you know why the above code isn't working, or you know a legit way of validating object's field just by name.

## EDIT 1:

- It seems like due to my poor way of explanation, there is misunderstanding.
- https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-groups , this doesn't work in this case, the validation is applied only with the declaration of the `PhoneType` property in other classes (`PersonContact`)
- I have two possible solutions, custom annotation and Jackson's converter.
- I have successfully applied the converter but couldn't make the custom annotation work.
- My custom annotation should be run after @JsonProperty, because it needs to have the field `PhoneType mobile` number to be deserialized.

Comment: In the controller, where you are deserializing the JSON to the java class, add @Valid annotation before the method parameters.

Comment: I'm sorry it might be due to might poor way of explanation. It's dynamic validation. I know everything about @Valid, @Max @Min, @Length and what not, but I need `PhoneType mobile` to have number with length of 10, but not for `PhoneType officeFax` and `PhoneType workPhone`

Comment: Why not use validation groups, then?

Comment: @crizzis sorry I still see that you don't get the question. There is a field named `number` inside `PhoneType` , it should have length of 10 when the `PhoneType` is used inside other class with name `PhoneType mobile`, and for other declaration of `PhoneType` in other classes, `number` should not have that validation rule

Comment: Ahh OK, I think I see the problem now. The validator seems OK, I understand other validation rules work?